# Is there a client library that implements Hybrid workflow for Node.js for IdentityServer4?

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, identityserver4, oidc-client-js

I know that there is a JavaScript client called *oidc-client.js* for IdentityServer4, but it implements the **Implicit** flow.  I need something that can implement the ***Hybrid*** or **Hybrid+PKSE** flow.  First, is there a client library out there that implements this flow (given that Node.js is at the server level running on the Google V8 engine and not in a browser)?  Second, is the Node.js server limited to just the ***Implicit*** flow?  Third, does it even matter since we're talking about server-to-server which doesn't require a "back channel" to be created to get the access token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out there's a dedicated IdentityServer4 library for Node.js called "openid-connect.js" that can be obtained here:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/openid-client